# Realisation of compose method

Tags: scala, generics

Help me please with understanding realisation own "compose" method for two function.
I have singnature
`def compose[A, B, C](g: B => C, f: A => B): A => C = ???`
And i want to write method "h" which is composition of two function (f and g) or g(f).

```
val res: Int = compose[Int, Int, Int]((b: Int) => b + 1, (a: Int) => a + 1)(1)
```

Comment: I do not understand, what is the question? writing compose is a trivial task, you already did it. Or are you asking how to improve type inference?

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake, you were right, it's a trivial task, but i found error in my solution
`... = (a: Int) => g(f(a))`
In my solution a is variable, but true answer is `... = (a) => g(f(a))`, where a is A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return a function that receives an x of type A and returns a function g which returns C and is applied to a function f applied to x

```scala
def compose[A, B, C](g: B => C, f: A => B): A => C = x => g(f(x))
```

Then you can define f and g

```scala
val f = (x:Int) => x * 2
val g = (x:Int) => x * 4
```

And h will be the composition of those two functions

```scala
val h = compose(f, g)
val result = h(42)
```